# Android BarcodeScanner library crash in 64bits devices

Tags: android, 64-bit, barcode-scanner, zbar

We have an application using the Zbar library from BarcodeScanner with gradle:

```
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.2'
```

Scanning works fine in all the devices except for those with 64bit. When we launch the scanner the screen turn black and we receive an exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.package.name-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/my.package.name-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libiconv.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
at me.dm7.barcodescanner.zbar.ZBarScannerView.(ZBarScannerView.java:31)
at my.package.name.activity.BarcodeActivity.onCreate(BarcodeActivity.java:19)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: According to Pitel it seems to be fixed in 1.8.4.

Comment: @esteban :- have you found the solution?

Comment: No, I've changed to API Vision.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fixed in 1.8.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try using version `1.9`

```
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9'
```